# How to get source of python module loaded in memory but the source of module is deleted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have accidentally deleted a module. But the module is still in memory of ipython notebook.
I tried using `inspect` to get the code. but since the source file is not available it fails to work.

Any idea on how to get the code of this module.

Comment: Thankfully it was in the spark context and I could find it there just now. :)